# Consulta en SQL usando COUNT

Tags: sql

Debo realizar una consulta que muestre la cantidad de clientes por país.

Ya tengo las tablas Pais (IdPais, Nombre) y Cliente (IdCliente, Nombre, IdPais), pero cuando trato de hacerla, obtengo el error:

> "Incorrect syntax near '*'. Expecting HOLDLOCK, or ID".

Aqui esta el codigo:

```
Select  
    Cliente.Nombre, Cliente.IdPais 
from 
    Cliente 
left outer join 
    Pais
count(*) on 
    Pais.IdPais = Cliente.IdPais
group by 
    Cliente.idCliente,Cliente.IdPais
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: tu consulta obviamente tiene un error debes hacer un subquery Select  
    Cliente.Nombre, Cliente.IdPais (select count(*) from Pais where  Pais.IdPais = Cliente.IdPais group by 
Pais.IdPais )
from 
    Cliente

Comment: por cierto agrega la base de datos que estas utilizando

Comment: Por el error que recibes, parece que estás usando SQL Server. ¿Puedes confirmar?

Answer (score 4):

Obviamente, no puedes usar la función `COUNT()` en medio de un join. En este caso, lo necesitas en la claúsula `SELECT`.

Para obtener la cantidad de clientes por país, necesitas hacer un join entre las 2 tablas agrupando por país. Y, de hecho, lo ideal es que sea un `LEFT JOIN`, para que incluya correctamente los países que no tienen clientes. Aunque tu consulta efectúa un `LEFT JOIN` también, lo estás haciendo a partir de la tabla incorrecta. Esta sería la consulta corregida:

```
select p.IdPais, p.Nombre, count(c.IdCliente) as cantidad_clientes
  from Pais p
  left join Cliente c
    on c.IdPais = p.IdPais
 group by p.IdPais, p.Nombre
```

Answer (score 0):

No puedes usar el `count` después del `from`, todos los campos que quieras mostrar, deben ser definidos después de la sentencia `select`

```
Select p.IdPais,count(idCliente) as total_clientes
from Pais p, Cliente c
where p.IdPais = c.IdPais
group by p.IdPais;
```

Comment: Recomiendo que agregues una descripcion o indicacion para que sea mas facil comprender tu respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que contar el número de clientes agrupando por cada país:

```
    Select count(c.idCliente) num_clientes, p.idPais 
    from cliente c, pais p 
    where c.idPais=p.idPais 
    group by p.idPais
```